# Multiple Virtual Machines Network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am using Virtualbox and I want to connect 3 virtual machines to act like theyre in one network (internet connection is not required). 
 I don't know how to do it and I couldn't understand this source https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html 
 Only thing I understood is that i need to use Internal networking but when Im running machines Im still getting the same IP address for all of them, and they cannot see each other. All of machines are running windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you need to setup a dhcp server for the internal network, which, for some reason I do not know, can only be done via CLI. So issue the following command:

```
VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname intnet1 --ip 192.168.173.254 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 192.168.173.1 --upperip 192.168.173.99 --enable
```

This will setup an internal network called `intnet1`, with parameters (chosen arbitrarily to avoid conflict with the most common subnets) that you can see from the line above.

Then modify your VMs to have an interface on this network: for instance, from the CLI,

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nicX intnet1
```

where you will have to use the name of your Virtual Machine, and X represents the number of the interface you want to assign to this network.

Or you can do this from the GUI: click on the machine name, then Network ->  Adapter X -> Enable Adapter, then for `Attached to` choose `Internal Network`, and for `name` choose `intnet1.`.